# Microsoft Outlook does not save files consistently

Tags: windows, file, email, unicode, outlook

I'm working on a .net project and interacting with outlook. The idea is that the user gets emails on his microsoft outlook client (outlook 2007 or outlook 2010). He chooses one of the emails and saves as Outlook Unicode message format (*.msg).

Then I took this file and read it by code.

The problem is that on certain machines, the file is saved with html tags, and in other machines the same email is saved without html tags and I use those tags to identify specific information of the email.

I've thought that it was a problem with the office or windows version, but don't, both machines has the same office version, the same windows version, and the same programs installed.

I have not been able to identify what is the difference between both machines. I'm sure it is related to unicode format or something.

NOTES:

The email format cannot be changed (no way, I've asked to the cliente).

The email contains tables inside it and the information I need is inside the tables.

I cannot do something different, so I need to have the client saving the email as explained before, and I have to process the email using a .net application created by me.

Does any body has any idea of what could be the problem here? I need to identify why both machine, with the same configuration, saves the same outlook email with different format.

I verify the email format opening it using notepad++